# Full author list for first citation in a chapter [apa.csl]

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, bibtex, csl, pandoc-citeproc

I'm writing my dissertation in R markdown. I am using bibtex, pandoc-citeproc, and apa.csl with bookdown. I have `new_session: yes` in my `_bookdown.yml` and compiling primarily to PDF (`documentclass:book`, `classoption: oneside`).

The system I have is correctly using the full author list in place of "et al." for the first time I cite a 3-6 author work. That said, my adviser wants the full author list for the first time I cite a work *per chapter*.

Is there an easy way to go about this?

Here is the apa.csl I'm using:

https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/apa.csl

Comment: What does your current "system" look like?

Comment: I'm using R studio, with bookdown, to translate from r markdown to tex and then xelatex to pdf. I'm OS agnostic, bc I have to use windows at school butter I use mac os or ubuntu at home. Under the hood it is using pandoc with citeproc for the transpiling. I have downloaded and included apa.csl. I was looking at the CSL to see if I could figure out how to adjust it to my needs, but I found it a bit opaque...

Comment: I do not know how to alter the way `pandoc-citeproc` works. I have the hope that a `biblatex` based approach would be more flexible. I have therefore raised https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503505/140850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that a `biblatex` based solution is indeed very flexible as [@moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) showed on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503526/140850). When one combines `style=apa` with `citerest=chapter` one gets the effect you are after. In a minimal R-markdown document:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: biblatex
documentclass: book
bibliography: biblatex-examples.bib
biblio-style: apa
biblatexoptions:
  - citereset=chapter
---

# Intro

[@herrmann] and [@yoon]

[@herrmann] and [@yoon]

# Method

[@herrmann] and [@yoon]

[@herrmann] and [@yoon]

# References
```

Make sure that your TeX system includes the `biber` program.